# Accessing eager-loaded objects in view laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, eager-loading, laravel-5.7

i have several models that are linked to one model Call
i have all the relationships defined and they work pretty okay but i have issues with eager loaded results.

i have this query:

```
    $callDetails =\App\Call::with(['client','subissues','subissues.issue','partner','district'])
                      ->where('call.id', '=', $id)
                      ->get();
```

that works fine in tinker returning

```
{"id":17400,
"client":{"id":18317,"name":"Yad  Kal","phonenumber":"0991234567","age":27,"gender":"Male"},
"district":{"id":1,"name":"Dedza"},
"comments":" He complained ",
"completeness":"complete",
"perpetrator":1,
"partner_id":119,"status":1,
"subissues":[{"id":1378,"name":"Issues of Dissatifaction","description":"Issues of Dissatifaction","issue":{"id":6,"name":"Emergency Response (World)","description":"Emergency response"},"pivot":{"call":17400,"subissue":1378}}],"partner":{"id":119,"name":"World"}}
```

but when trying to access client with `$callDetails->client`, it returns the client id only.
and `$callDetails->client->name` returns an error.

i don't know what am doing wrong but all the eagerloaded results are giving me headaches!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you don't have in your table column with name `client` or you don't have any property in your model with name `client`. When relationship and field/property has exact same name (in your case `client`) it might cause problems, so in such case you should rename either relationship or field/property